# Defining an array in a database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I downloaded a zip file from a database but am unable to find what I should put in the `$file_names = array()`? When I run the file the error displayed is `No ID Selected`

I think that this is because there is nothing inside the `array()`. Can someone help me define the `array()`?

```
<?php
$file_names = array();
// Make sure an id was passed
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Get the id into string (in case of an array)
    $id_pass = implode(",",$_GET['id']);
    // Make sure the name is in fact a valid
    if ($id_pass <= 0) {
        die ('No ID Selected!');
    } else {
        // codes to connect to the database is here

        // Fetch the file information
        $query = "select * from docu  where id = {$id_pass};";
var_dump($result);
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if ($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                //zip function

                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $filename = "export_" . date('Y.m.d H.i.s') . ".zip";

                if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE |   ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== true) {
                    echo "Cannot Open for writing";
                }


                $ext = $row['name'] . ".pdf"; // taking file name from DB and adding extension separately
                $zip->addFromString($ext, $row['content']); //adding blob data from DB
                $zip->close();

                header("Content-disposition: inline; filename='.$filename'");
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                readfile($filename);
                unlink($filename);
            }
        }

        // Free the mysqli resources     
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
```

result of `var_dump($result)`:

`object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(22) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Here is the HTML Form.

```
<html>
<form action="test.php" method="get"/>
<?php
//codes to connect to the database is here
 mysqli_select_db($con, "images");
 $query = "SELECT id, name FROM docu  order by id";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error, query failed');

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Database is empty <br>";
} else {
    while ((list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='id[]'>";
        echo $name . " " . $id . " " . "<br>"; //id and name removed
    }
}
?>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</html>
```

Comment: you should use `prepare` to prevent injection to your code

Comment: Nope. its because you're not getting your id in here `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {`
`$id_pass = implode(",",$_GET['id']);`

Comment: How do i get the id? @DipenShah

Comment: Show your html form (front end related code). I can't help you without that.

Comment: <form action="" method="get"/>
      <?php
    //codes to connect to the database
    mysqli_select_db($con, "im");
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM docu order by id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('failed');

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "Database is empty <br>";
    } else {
        while ((list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='id[]'>";
            echo $name . " " . $id . " " . "<br>"; 
        }
    }
    ?>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

Comment: Here the codes @DipenShah

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code in the question itself. This is totally unreadable right now.

Comment: I have added in the html form. Thanks in advance. @DipenShah

Comment: Are you able to see the ids in a checkbox form in your html? i.e. in the browser?

Comment: Ya. I am able to view it. @DipenShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this. In your while loop:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$id' value='$id'>";
```

and it should work.

**Explanation:** When you post a form on your server, the checkbox's value is taken by the `value` contained in it. Since you were not putting anything in your value, you were not able to get the `id` on your server.

Comment: It works,  Do i need to include anything in the array()? Cause i still can't download any file.

Comment: What file is that? I don't see any front end code regarding a file upload. all I see is checkboxes being generated.

Comment: I have uploaded files beforehand and now it is in the database. For now i want to retrieve the file from my database and download it into zip file.

Comment: Files CANNOT be stored in the database (Not a good practice) It looks like you stored the path in the database. and you're trying to retrieve the path. In that case, have you checked the results of your `$result` and `$row`? Try doing a `var_dump` on those variables. And see if the file actually exists on your server.

Comment: Other than that this answer solves your problem of `id` not being passed, so you should mark this answer as correct so that it helps future StackOverflow users.

Comment: I used the var_dump and this is what i get. Can i know what this means? object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(22) ["type"]=> int(0) }.

Comment: Please put this in the question in code format. This is not readable.

Comment: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(22) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Which variable did you `var_dump`?

Comment: Try `$row` too. And please edit your question and put the code there not in comments.